# Showing that two integrals are the same

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

Assume $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is integrable on the interval $I = [a, b]$ and let $c \in (a, b)$. Then define
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
  f(x) &, x\neq c \\
  y &, x = c\,.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

Is $\int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm d x = \int_a^b g(x) \,\mathrm d x$?

#### My thoughts

Since $f$ is integrable, then is $g$, as they differ only by a single value $y$ at one point $c$ in the interval $(a, b)$, and that value is implied to be finite. The integrability of both functions implies that they are bounded, meaning there exist $M_1, M_2 \in \mathbb R^+$,
so that
\begin{equation}
M_1 > |f(x)|
\quad\text{and}\quad
M_2 > |g(x)| = \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
|f(x)| &, x \neq c \\
|y| &, x = c\,.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

As both functions are bounded, we can also conclude, that at least for a certain $M \in \mathbb R^+$,
\begin{equation}
  M > |f(x) - g(x)| = \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    0 &, x \neq c \\
    |f(x) - y| &, x = c\,.
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}

Now, following the known rules of integration we can conclude that
\begin{align}
\left| \int_a^b f(x) - g(x)\, \mathrm d x \right|
&= \left| \int_a^c f(x) - g(x)\, \mathrm d x + \int_c^b f(x)\,\,\mathrm d x \right| \\
&\leq \left| \int_a^c f(x) - g(x)\, \mathrm d x \right| + \left|\int_c^b f(x) - g(x)\,\,\mathrm d x \right| \\
&< M(c - a) + M(b - c)\,.
\end{align}

Now all that is left to show is, that we can choose $M = \varepsilon > 0$, and we are done. But how do I do that?

Comment: integrability does not imply boundedness. However, to see that both integrals are the same, it suffices to note that the lebesgue measure of the singleton $\{c\}$ is zero.

Comment: @Lukas Rollier: clasical Riemann integrability certainly does entail boundedness, and it is quite likely that the question poster is working with elementary exercises to assimilate basic Riemann integration. Speaking of higher notions of Lebesgue measure and integration is perhaps premature.

Comment: Right. In that case, I would suggest taking an integral from $a$ to $c-\epsilon$ and from $c+\epsilon$ to $b$ of $f-g$. Both of these have to be $0$ since $f-g=0$ there. Then the remaining integral is smaller than or equal to $2\epsilon M$. Since we have taken $\epsilon$ arbitrarily, we are done.

Comment: @LukasRollier That seems like a sensible approach.